# Уменьшение количества товаров в корзине JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, корзина

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить, есть код (нашёл его на ютубе в видеоуроке по созданию корзины), при добавлении товара в корзину всё ок, товар плюсуется, при уменьшении товара, значение доходит до 0, а дальше идёт в минус, то-есть -1, -2,-5,-10 и т. д =(
Как это пофиксить? Кто подскажет буду очень сильно благодарен =)

````
```
var cart = {};
function loadCart() {
    //Проверка есть ли в localStorage запись cart
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        //если есть - расшифровываю и записываю в переменную cart
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        console.log(isEmpty(cart));
            showCart();
        }
    else {
        $('.main-cart').html('Корзина пуста!');
    }
}

function showCart() {
    //вывод корзины
    if (!isEmpty(cart)) {
            $('.main-cart').html('<center><h3>Корзина пуста!</h3></center>');
        }
        else {
    $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
        var goods = data;
        var out = '';
        var itog = 0;
        for (var id in cart) {
            out += `<button data-id="${id}" class="del-goods">x</button>`;
            out += `<img src="images\\${goods[id].img}">`;
            out += ` ${goods[id].name  }`;
            out += `  <button data-id="${id}" class="minus-goods">-</button>`  ;
            out += `${cart[id]  }`;
            out += `  <button data-id="${id}" class="plus-goods">+</button>`  ;
            out += cart[id]*goods[id].cost;
            itog += cart[id]*goods[id].cost;
            out += '<br>';
        }
        out += '<p class="gavnaz">Сумма заказа: </p>'+itog+'<br>';
        $('.main-cart').html(out);
        $('.del-goods').on('click', delGoods);
        $('.plus-goods').on('click', plusGoods);
        $('.minus-goods').on('click', minusGoods);
    });
        }
}

function delGoods() {
    //Удаляем товар из корзины
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    delete cart[id];
    saveCart();
    showCart();
}

function plusGoods() {
    //Добавляем товар в корзину
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    cart[id]++;
    saveCart();
    showCart();
}

function minusGoods() {
    //Уменьшаем товар в корзине
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (cart[id==1]) {
        delete cart[id];
    }
    else {
        cart[id]--;
    }
    cart[id]--;
    saveCart();
    showCart();
}

function saveCart() {
    //Сохраняю корзину в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));//Корзину в строку
}

function isEmpty(object) {
    //Проверка корзины на пустоту
    for (var key in object)
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) return true;
    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadCart();
});
```
````

Comment: У вас `cart[id==1]` в условии, возможно причина в этом. Попробуйте `cart[id]===1`.

Comment: Теперь у вас дублируется `cart[id]--;`. Удалите последний `cart[id]--;` в `minusGoods`. И проверьте как работает.

Comment: Аааа, оно работает!!! =) Спасибо! Можно я у тебя ещё 1 вопросик спрошу, как сделать, не будет нагло? =) сейчас залью на хостинг мини корзину, когда добавляешь товары в неё, чтобы показывало не так : 5шт.одного товара, 10шт. другого , а общее число всех товаров сразу? как тут -> https://prnt.sc/s5vxsu

Comment: Ну пока что немного непонятно, что именно не работает или работает не так как надо.

Comment: А вы откуда свой проект взяли, что испытываете такие трудности?

Comment: tg - @denisstep99